# Cordova replaces JS fetch URL ftom http to https

Tags: android, cordova, https

First of all, please note that this is my first time using Cordova.

## Context

I am developing a website for a school group project during which we wrote an app in pure HTML, CSS and JS for the front-end and pure node.js for back-end. We now need to port this app to Cordova.

## Problem

When I try to login an error pops up in the console (I am using Chrome DevTools)
[image: Login error]

As we can see, the app is trying to contact an https URL.
However, as the code shows, this is what I want to be called (uses http)

```
const response = await fetch("http://MY_URL:8000/api/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
});
```

I do not want to use https and would like Cordova to let me do requests using http.

## More info

The server is successfully contacted through the already existing projet served on the server and also using Postman.

This is what my `context.xml` looks like. It might be kind of messy because I tried resolving the issue with what I saw online but can't understand what is really happening here.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="my.id.here" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>name</name>
    <description>desc</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        author
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="scheme" value="http" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://MY_URL/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <access origin="http://MY_URL" />

    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <icon src="res/icon.png" platform="android" width="512" height="512" density="hdpi" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
        <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
        <feature name="SplashScreen" >
            <param
                    name="android-package"
                    value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
            <param
                    name="onload"
                    value="true" />
        </feature>

        <feature name="Vibration">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" />
        </feature>

        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" />

        <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxhdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxxhdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" />

        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <application name="requestLegacyExternalStorage=" value="true" />
    </platform>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="6.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="2.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="3.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="3.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.5" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to remove this tag from my html file

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`